# How to know if copying directory is complete

Tags: linux, bash

If someone (i.e. my VPS provider), does the following command, how can I from my ssh know if the copy is complete?  Thanks

```
cp /home/abc/hugeDir /home/cba
```

Comment: In Linux/Unix commands are synchronous unless you send them to background (e.g. by a ` &` appended). The `cp` command is visible to all users, unless the admin has enabled obfuscations.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Some answerers, including the one you accepted, assume you mean "has completed" while others assume you mean that whether anything was missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just check the process list:

```
ps aux | grep cp
```

If the prcoess is finished, it will vanish from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use [md5deep](http://md5deep.sourceforge.net/md5deep.html) on the source directory and when they tell you the copy is complete use it on the destination directory, the output hash should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches; however, I find one to be very easy and simple to apply.

I recommend to use rsync and start a data transfer; if no files are copied, the initial copy must have been complete.

Example command:

```
rsync -Hav --progress /home/abc/hugeDir /home/cba
```

If you want to know what the options mean simply type in "man rsync".

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP means.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how much they are supposed to transfer you can `watch du -hs /path/to/target/dir` to see when it reaches the right size.

Comment: You can edit answers, no need to delete and repost.

Comment: Yeah, but since the answer contained two solutions it was better to split it. Also, the other solution was, as you said, infeasible.

Comment: Running `du` in `watch` could be very expensive.